# Show Form Hidden Fields in Model Window to accept user input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

My objective is to implement the following functionality:

The form will contain several fields, including uid, name, course, field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, and field8. Among these fields, only uid, name, course, field1, and field2 should be visible on the page initially. The remaining fields should be hidden from the user. When the user clicks the "Details" button, a model window should appear, displaying fields for entering values in field3 through field8. After the user enters values in these fields and closes the dialog, the "Add New" and "Delete" buttons can be used to add a new row to the table or delete a row from the table, respectively. Whenever a new row is added, all fields should be created with names suffixed by the row number. For example, when the user adds a second row, the fields should be named uid_2, name_2, course_2, field1_2, field2_2, field3_2, field4_2, field5_2, field6_2, field7_2, and field8_2, with field3_2 through field8_2 initially hidden.

For example, when the user clicks on the first row, the model window should display field3_1, field4_1, field5_1, field6_1, field7_1, and field8_1 for editing. Similarly, when user clicks on 2nd row it should the model window should display field3_2, field4_2, field5_2, field6_2, field7_2, and field8_2 for editing and entering data in those fields.

Currently, everything is working correctly except that the values entered in model window fields(field3_n through field8_n) are not showing when we close the model window and go back and check it again. I want the model window to show only the fields corresponding to the selected row.

How can I modify the code to achieve this functionality?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Template with Form</title>
    <!-- Add Bootstrap stylesheet & Necessary CDN Links-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 30px;">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title float-left">Employee Details</h4>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success float-right" id="add-new">Add New </button>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form id="my-form">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>UID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Course</th>
                        <th>Field 1</th>
                        <th>Field 2</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="uid_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="course_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="field1_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="field2_1" class="form-control"></td>

                        <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field3_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field4_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field5_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field6_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field7_1" class="form-control"></td>
                        <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field8_1" class="form-control"></td>

                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info details" data-row="1">Details</button></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-row="1">Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Add new row
        $("#add-new").click(function () {
            var row_count = $("table tbody tr").length;
            var row_html = '<tr>\
                            <td><input type="text" name="uid_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td><input type="text" name="name_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td><input type="text" name="course_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td><input type="text" name="field1_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td><input type="text" name="field2_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field3_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field4_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field5_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field6_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field7_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td style="display: none"><input type="text" name="field8_' + (row_count + 1) + '" class="form-control"></td>\
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info details" data-row="' + (row_count + 1) + '">Details</button></td>\
                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" data-row="' + (row_count + 1) + '">Delete</button></td>\
                            </tr>';
            $("table tbody").append(row_html);
        });

        // Delete row
        $("table").on("click", ".delete", function () {
            var row_count = $("table tbody tr").length;
            if (row_count > 1) {
                var row_index = $(this).attr("data-row");
                $("table tbody tr:nth-child(" + row_index + ")").remove();
                // Refresh field names
                $("table tbody tr").each(function (index) {
                    var row_index = index + 1;
                    $(this).find("input").each(function () {
                        var old_name = $(this).attr("name");
                        var new_name = old_name.replace(/\d+/, row_index);
                        $(this).attr("name", new_name);
                    });
                    $(this).find(".details").attr("data-row", row_index);
                    $(this).find(".delete").attr("data-row", row_index);
                });
            } else {
                alert("At least one row should be there");
            }
        });

        // Show details modal
        $("table").on("click", ".details", function () {
            //alert('Showing Details');
            var row_index = $(this).attr("data-row");
            var modal_html = '<div class="modal fade" id="details-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-modal-label" aria-hidden="true">\
                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">\
                                        <div class="modal-content">\
                                            <div class="modal-header">\
                                                <h5 class="modal-title">Details for Row ' + row_index + '</h5>\
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">\
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>\
                                                </button>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class="modal-body">\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <label for="field3_' + row_index + '">Field 3:</label>\
                                                    <input type="text" name="field3_' + row_index + '" class="form-control">\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <label for="field4_' + row_index + '">Field 4:</label>\
                                                    <input type="text" name="field4_' + row_index + '" class="form-control">\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <label for="field5_' + row_index + '">Field 5:</label>\
                                                    <input type="text" name="field5_' + row_index + '" class="form-control">\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <label for="field6_' + row_index + '">Field 6:</label>\
                                                    <input type="text" name="field6_' + row_index + '" class="form-control">\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <label for="field7_' + row_index + '">Field 7:</label>\
                                                    <input type="text" name="field7_' + row_index + '" class="form-control">\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="form-group">\
                                                    <label for="field8_' + row_index + '">Field 8:</label>\
                                                    <input type="text" name="field8_' + row_index + '" class="form-control">\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                            <div class="modal-footer">\
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"  data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>';
            $("body").append(modal_html);
            //$(".modal").modal();
            $("#details-modal").modal("show");
        });

        // Remove modal from DOM when closed
        $("body").on("hidden.bs.modal", ".modal", function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```